# Hidden data annotation wont hide field in EditorFor()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

I cant seem to get why my hidden data annotation in my model class are not working.

My model:

```
using ...
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Store.Domain.Entities{
    public class MyModel {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int ModelID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my view i call the Model like this:

```
@model Store.Domain.Entities.MyModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller")){
    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })
    </div>
}
...
```

web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
   <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Store.WebUI" />
    <add namespace="Store.WebUI.HtmlHelpers" />
   </namespaces>
  </pages>
 </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Basic - but it will show fields for all properties - also the ModelID which as get HiddenInput??? What could cause this???

Comment: i tried without the parameter - it still doesnt work??

Answer (score 2):

[Not able to duplicate it (DotNetFiddle Example)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lcANVz).  Generated source:

```
<form action="/Controller/Method" method="post">    
  <div class="form-group">
    <input data-val="true" 
           data-val-number="The field ModelID must be a number." 
           data-val-required="The ModelID field is required." 
           id="ModelID" 
           name="ModelID" 
           type="hidden" 
           value="0" />
    <div class="editor-label">
      <label for="ModelName">ModelName</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <input class="text-box single-line" 
             data-val="true" 
             data-val-required="The ModelName field is required." 
             id="ModelName" 
             name="ModelName" 
             type="text" 
             value="" /> 
      <span class="field-validation-valid" 
            data-valmsg-for="ModelName" 
            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The ModelID is a Hidden Input.

The `HiddenInputAttribute` is in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace and should be in the `web.config` file in the `views` directory like the following: (mvc 5 example)

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: hmm weird? Could it be a assembly reference?

Comment: Hmm.. seem right, ive uploaded my system setup in my question

Comment: Do you have your own `EditorFor()` that is custom in your HtmlHelpers?

Comment: Do you have an EditorTemplate that overrides the default template?